# Calculating Confidence intervals for glmmTMB prediction with zero-inflation

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate confidence intervals of predictions made from a glmmTMB model with zero inflation.

I have looked through a few issues posted on github and the original paper describing glmmTMB. However, it appears glmmTMB has changed slightly and I am very confused as to the proper method to use.

Here is what I've looked at so far:
- https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/324
- https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/378
- https://www.biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/suppl/2017/05/01/132753.DC1/132753-2.pdf

Currently, I am simply taking the prediction and se on the response scale (since this should include the ZI term as well), converting back to the log scale, calculating the 0.95 confidence interval and converting back to the response scale. (see code below).

```
library(glmmTMB)
data("Salamanders")


fit = glmmTMB(count~spp + cover + mined +(1|site), 
        ziformula=~spp + mined,
        dispformula = ~DOY,
        data = Salamanders, 
        family=nbinom2)


newdata <- expand.grid(
  site = "new",
  spp = unique(Salamanders$spp),
  mined = factor(c("yes", "no"), levels =  levels(Salamanders$mined)),
  cover = seq(from = min(Salamanders$cover),
              to = max(Salamanders$cover),
              length = 25
              ),
  DOY = mean(Salamanders$DOY)
  )

preds <- predict(fit, newdata, se=T, allow.new.levels = T, type='response')
newdata$pred=preds$fit
newdata$se = preds$se.fit
newdata$ulimit = exp(log(newdata$pred)+(qnorm(0.975)*log(newdata$se)))
newdata$llimit = exp(log(newdata$pred)-(qnorm(0.975)*log(newdata$se)))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=newdata, aes(x=cover, y = pred))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=llimit, ymax=ulimit, fill=mined), alpha = 0.25)+
  geom_line(aes(color = mined), size=1)+
  facet_wrap(~spp)
```

Since the documentation shows other ways of doing this, I would like some reassurance that I calculated the upper and lower limits correctly.

Comment: Seems more appropriate for a venue that deals with methods questions. The obvious would be the R-SIG-mixed-models mailing list.

Comment: In point of fact there appears to be a posting today on that mailing list that recommends bootstrapped CI's and offers suggestions about a recent version of a package on Github for that process. (And I just noticed it was from Michael Whitby, so it appears you took my advice.)