# How to compute confidence intervals around Zero-inflated GLMM predictions where an offset is applied

Tags: r, predict, mixed-models, confidence-interval

I've built a series of glmm's using the R package glmmTMB, all of which have fixed (categorical and continuous) effects, a random effect, an offset, and some of which have a single zero-inflation term.

I am using these models to make inferential predictions for the purpose of mapping.  As part of this process I would like to produce corresponding uncertainty maps for the predictions, this requires calculating confidence intervals for the predicted values.  The only method I can find does not consider the offset in the calculation of the linear predictor (compared to predict.glmmTMB which does) and associated CI values.  I would like to report the response at a sensible scale, relative to that which it is measured at, ie the offset.

From my understanding, one cannot just multiply up the predicted value and confidence intervals once they are at the scale of the response. My question is how can one incorporate the offset into the manual calculation of the predictor and estimation of the CI's?

I've tried reading around the various glmmTMB documentation and found a well laid-out example method in the appendix of [this paper](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-066/RJ-2017-066.pdf).  However, the example in the paper uses a model without an offset.

Furthermore, I've found a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991471/calculating-confidence-intervals-for-glmmtmb-prediction-with-zero-inflation) and followed the links provided there-in to other sources of information.  This line of information eventually led me back to the initial paper described above without answering my question.

```
## From the example in the appendix of Brooks et al (2017): 
library("glmmTMB")
library(MASS)
data("Salamanders")

## Build Model
zinbm3 = glmmTMB(count~spp * mined +(1|site),
                 zi=~spp * mined, 
                 Salamanders, 
                 family=nbinom2)

## Create new dataset for predictions
newdata0 = unique(Salamanders[,c("mined","spp")])

## Make Predictions
X.cond = model.matrix(lme4::nobars(formula(zinbm3)[-2]), newdata0) 
#### The line above is where the offset is dropped.
beta.cond = fixef(zinbm3)$cond
pred.cond = X.cond %*% beta.cond 

ziformula = zinbm3$modelInfo$allForm$ziformula
X.zi = model.matrix(lme4::nobars(ziformula), newdata0)
beta.zi = fixef(zinbm3)$zi
pred.zi = X.zi %*% beta.zi

pred.ucount = exp(pred.cond)*(1-plogis(pred.zi))

## Simulate and estimate 95% confidence intervals
set.seed(101)
pred.condpar.psim = mvrnorm(1000,mu=beta.cond,Sigma=vcov(zinbm3)$cond)
pred.cond.psim = X.cond %*% t(pred.condpar.psim)
pred.zipar.psim = mvrnorm(1000,mu=beta.zi,Sigma=vcov(zinbm3)$zi)
pred.zi.psim = X.zi %*% t(pred.zipar.psim)
pred.ucount.psim = exp(pred.cond.psim)*(1-plogis(pred.zi.psim))
ci.ucount = t(apply(pred.ucount.psim,1,quantile,c(0.025,0.975)))
ci.ucount = data.frame(ci.ucount)

## Combine predicted value and CI values at response scale
pred.ucount = data.frame(newdata0, pred.ucount, ci.ucount)
```

At what point in this manual calculation of the predicted response and confidence intervals could one account for an offset, as is done in predict.glmmTMB?